# Apache Flume not Proceeding with Twitter Stream

Tags: apache, hdfs, flume, flume-ng, flume-twitter

Trying to get Apache Flume tweets in HortonWorks. (Using Tutorial Point Reference)

Flume configured right. Here is flume.conf

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = <1bL3mTHJBheYNye8cE4vHKBZ8>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = <iO3f2GxrrRjtF88eA4AH6AHncz4VbmxxT22fHWzuxCLaejoxdD>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = <22976784986-nfj6qEkECeNfs3AeDLDCqtlMOCl9B1iHb8cgIF>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = <jnNPtmBxlGA8hQq5ZyxjCJLdyiKN97Xa1JTifpmp5BREf>

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, big data, analytics, bigdata, cloudera, data science, data scientiest, business intelligence, mapreduce, data warehouse, data warehousing, mahout, hbase, nosql, newsql, businessintelligence, cloudcomputing

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/flume/tweets
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 1000

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

After I run the flume agent:

```
bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/twitter.conf Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent
```

The screen freezes at this point. Let me know how to proceed? or shall I wait for long due to sandbox?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImpBx.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this flume.conf**

```
#flume.conf for twitter

TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = <required>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = <required>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = <required> 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = <required> 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, big data, analytics, bigdata, cloudera, data science, data scientiest, business intelligence, mapreduce, data warehouse, data warehousing, mahout, hbase, nosql, newsql, businessintelligence, cloudcomputing

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/flume/tweets
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

**Command to run Flume agent**

`bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/twitter.conf Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent`

If you have doubts you can check official page:
https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example/blob/master/flume-sources/flume.conf